# @MapKeyColumn in hibernate default value error

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to implement the below example for `@MapKeyColumn`. There is a `OnetoMany` relationship between the `Company` and `Persons`. However I am getting the below error when I try to persist the Person instance since that is the owner of the relationship:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'name_emp' doesn't have a default value
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:975)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1114)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1062)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1383)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1047)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
... 20 more
```

Person Entity

```
 @Entity

public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id;

    String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
//@JoinColumn(name="company_id")
    Company company;

    public Person()
    {}

    public Person(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Company getcompany() {
        return company;
    }


    public void setcompany(Company c) {
        this.company = c;
    }

}
```

Company Entity

```
 @Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id;

    String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST,mappedBy="company")
    @MapKeyColumn(name="name_emp")
    Map<String,Person> persons= new HashMap<>();

    public Company()
    {}


    public Company(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Map<String,Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(Map<String,Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

MainTest

```
    Person p1 = new Person("jack");
    Company c= new Company("ABCORP");
    p1.setcompany(c);
    session.persist(p1);
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be an `@Talbe` in your code?

Comment: Hibernate automatically adds the @Table annotations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might occur because the relationship is not set in the company instance.

Could you try to add the person to the company ether by calling `c.getPersons().add(p1.getName(), p1)` or by changing the `setcompany(...)` method to

```
public void setcompany(Company c) {
    c.getPersons().add(this.getName(), this)
    this.company = c;
}
```

Comment: Nope. Still the same issue

Comment: How do you create the database schema? Does it help to provide a default value for name_emp like `name_emp varchar(255) DEFAULT 'none'`

Comment: it should not be db dependent. Since in other columns the hibernate itself creates the columns and does not depend on db

Comment: Could you provide a sample project? @ghostrider